# How do I set flex properties of the innerText of a flex box container?

Tags: css, flexbox

If your flex box container itself has text inside it (innerText), then that text apparently becomes part of the flex layout. But how do I control it with settings such as flex-basis and flex-grow?
Is there any way to control it?

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
   Sample text
   <div class="b"></div>
   <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
  display: flex;
}
.b {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
.c {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

I want to control the flex properties of "Sample text".

And yes, I know the problem would be solved by just putting that text in a node of it's own, but I'm dealing with a list of +10k items so I'm trying to keep the node count at a minimum.

Comment: no there is no way, you can try to control the `b` in order to achieve what you want. So what you want?

Comment: Thanks, @TemaniAfif , the problem is that there is actually yet another child in there, which I failed to mention but I've added it now to the question, so I need to control that text somehow.

Comment: Yes I got this, but what should be the final result? you want to control in order to obtain what? probably we will find a workaround based on your final need

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thanks again. The final result is that I want that text to occupy the full space and the remaining two elements to be pushed to the right edge... basically the flex-stretch of the text should be 1, and the other two elements should have a fixed width and their stretch and shrink set to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On idea to control the text is to consider both pseudo element that you wrap around the text where you can apply the flex properties and achieve what you want:

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
}
.a:before,
.a:after{
  content:"";
  background:pink;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  
}

.b {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  background:blue;
  order:2; /*we place them at the end*/
}

.c {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  background:red; 
  order:2; /*we place them at the end*/
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  Sample text
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

You simply need to *imagine* the correct values to apply to the pseudo elements in order to achieve the needed result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your proposed solution set me on the right path! I will be able to solve it with pseudo elements, just like you suggested :)